# Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17.06\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Tags: intellij-17

> Configure project :
> Java: 17.0.6, JVM: 17.0.6+9-LTS-190 (Oracle Corporation), Arch: amd64

> Task :compileJava UP-TO-DATE
> Task :processResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :classes UP-TO-DATE
> Task :downloadMcpConfig
> Task :extractSrg UP-TO-DATE
> Task :createSrgToMcp UP-TO-DATE
> Task :downloadMCMeta UP-TO-DATE
> Task :downloadAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :extractNatives UP-TO-DATE
> Task :makeSrcDirs
> Task :prepareRuns
> Task :prepareRunClient
> Task :prepareRunClientCompile UP-TO-DATE

> Task :runClient
> 2023-10-16 16:07:01,379 main WARN Advanced terminal features are not available in this environment
> [16:07:01] [main/INFO] [cp.mo.mo.Launcher/MODLAUNCHER]: ModLauncher running: args [--launchTarget, forgeclientuserdev, --version, MOD_DEV, --assetIndex, 5, --assetsDir, C:\Users\molly.gradle\caches\forge_gradle\assets, --gameDir, ., --fml.forgeVersion, 47.2.1, --fml.mcVersion, 1.20.1, --fml.forgeGroup, net.minecraftforge, --fml.mcpVersion, 20230612.114412]
> [16:07:01] [main/INFO] [cp.mo.mo.Launcher/MODLAUNCHER]: ModLauncher 10.0.9+10.0.9+main.dcd20f30 starting: java version 17.0.6 by Oracle Corporation; OS Windows 11 arch amd64 version 10.0
> [16:07:01] [main/DEBUG] [cp.mo.mo.LaunchServiceHandler/MODLAUNCHER]: Found launch services [fmlclientdev,forgeclient,minecraft,forgegametestserverdev,fmlserveruserdev,fmlclient,fmldatauserdev,forgeserverdev,forgeserveruserdev,forgeclientdev,forgeclientuserdev,forgeserver,forgedatadev,fmlserver,fmlclientuserdev,fmlserverdev,forgedatauserdev,testharness,forgegametestserveruserdev]
> [16:07:01] [main/DEBUG] [cp.mo.mo.NameMappingServiceHandler/MODLAUNCHER]: Found naming services : [srgtomcp]
> [16:07:01] [main/DEBUG] [cp.mo.mo.LaunchPluginHandler/MODLAUNCHER]: Found launch plugins: [mixin,eventbus,slf4jfixer,object_holder_definalize,runtime_enum_extender,capability_token_subclass,accesstransformer,runtimedistcleaner]
> [16:07:01] [main/DEBUG] [cp.mo.mo.TransformationServicesHandler/MODLAUNCHER]: Discovering transformation services
> [16:07:01] [main/DEBUG] [ne.mi.fm.lo.FMLPaths/CORE]: Path GAMEDIR is C:\Data\Repositories\Coding\Forge-Tutorial-1.20.X\run
> [16:07:01] [main/DEBUG] [ne.mi.fm.lo.FMLPaths/CORE]: Path MODSDIR is C:\Data\Repositories\Coding\Forge-Tutorial-1.20.X\run\mods
> [16:07:01] [main/DEBUG] [ne.mi.fm.lo.FMLPaths/CORE]: Path CONFIGDIR is C:\Data\Repositories\Coding\Forge-Tutorial-1.20.X\run\config
> [16:07:01] [main/DEBUG] [ne.mi.fm.lo.FMLPaths/CORE]: Path FMLCONFIG is C:\Data\Repositories\Coding\Forge-Tutorial-1.20.X\run\config\fml.toml
> [16:07:01] [main/DEBUG] [cp.mo.mo.TransformationServicesHandler/MODLAUNCHER]: Found additional transformation services from discovery services:
> [16:07:01] [main/INFO] [ne.mi.fm.lo.ImmediateWindowHandler/]: Loading ImmediateWindowProvider fmlearlywindow
> [16:07:01] [main/INFO] [EARLYDISPLAY/]: Trying GL version 4.6
> #
> # A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
> #
> #  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00007ffd3ace2b60, pid=5728, tid=6892
> #
> # JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (17.0.6+9) (build 17.0.6+9-LTS-190)
> # Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (17.0.6+9-LTS-190, mixed mode, sharing,   tiered, compressed oops, compressed class ptrs, g1 gc, windows-amd64)
> # Problematic frame:
> # C  [atio6axx.dll+0x192b60]
> #
> # No core dump will be written. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
> #
> # An error report file with more information is saved as:
> # C:\Data\Repositories\Coding\Forge-Tutorial-1.20.X\run\hs_err_pid5728.log
> #
> # If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
> #   https://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
> # The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
> # See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
> #

```
[error occurred during error reporting (), id 0xc0000005, EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00007ffd3cacda79]


> Task :runClient FAILED

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if  they   come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/8.1.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
10 actionable tasks: 3 executed, 7 up-to-date

Publishing a build scan to scans.gradle.com requires accepting the Gradle Terms of Service  defined     at https://gradle.com/terms-of-service. Do you accept these terms? [yes, no] 
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

I tried to runClient and I expected it to open Minecraft.
```

Comment: The actual problem is not what's in your post title. It's in the line that contains **A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment: # # EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00007ffd3ace2b60, pid=5728, tid=6892 **. The error message also says **An error report file with more information is saved as: # C:\Data\Repositories\Coding\Forge-Tutorial-1.20.X\run\hs_err_pid5728.log**. Did you look at that file to see what it contained? Did you use `--warning-mode all` to look at what is deprecated to see if that might be the issue?